# conditional binary operator expected in shell script

Tags: shell

I was trying a simple program to compare the string values stored on a log file and was getting an error as below,

```
#!/bin/bash

check_val1="successful"
check_val2="completed"
log="/compile.log"

if [[ grep $check_val1 $log -ne $check_val1 || grep $check_val2 $log -ne $check_val2 ]];
then
        echo "No Error"
else
        echo "Error"
fi


Error:

./simple.sh: line 7: conditional binary operator expected
./simple.sh: line 7: syntax error near `$check_val1'
./simple.sh: line 7: `if [[ grep $check_val1 $log -ne $check_val1 || grep $check_val2 $log -ne $check_val2 ]];'
```

Comment: Just curious -- Is there a way to use the `[[ ... ]]` but still make it work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Problem is in your `if [[...]]` expression where you are using 2 `grep` commands without using command substitution i.e. `$(grep 'pattern' file)`.

However instead of:

```
if [[ grep $check_val1 $log -ne $check_val1 || grep $check_val2 $log -ne $check_val2 ]]; then
```

You can use `grep -q`:

```
if grep -q -e "$check_val1" -e "$check_val2" "$log"; then
```

As per `man grep`:

```
-q, --quiet, --silent
         Quiet mode: suppress normal output.  grep will only search a file until a match 
         has been found, making searches potentially less expensive.
```

Comment: I executed like this on the shell  grep -q -e "success" -e "leaving" compile.log > a
cat a => was not listing any vlaue

Comment: `grep -q` doesn't print anything on stdout. It just returns success/fail return value. If you remove `-q` then it will print values.

Comment: The log file contains the string "success" and "leaving".[root@a a~]# grep -e "success" -e "leaving" compile.log
[root@aa~]# grep -e "success" -e "leaving" compile.log > a
[root@aa~]# cat a
[root@aa ~]# grep -e "suess" -e "leang" compile.log > a
[root@aa ~]# cat a

Comment: I tried with the correct strings as well as wrong strings. but i'm not getting any o/p for the above grep

Comment: Hmm that is strange, does `grep -e "success" compile.log` prints anything?

Comment: Nope. It also didnt print anything

Comment: ok in that case `success` is not present in `compile.log`. Try with `-i` using `grep -i "success" compile.log`

Comment: I got the line where the success was with -i option. I understood my mistake, that i was searching for lower case. But it was with uppercase in the log file.

Comment: One more doubt, suppose if i wanted to search for two patterns in the same file and if both the patterns are present I can enter inside the if loop. TO do this, can I use like if grep -i "SUCCESS" -i "Leaving" "compile.log";then echo"no error" else echo "error" fi

Comment: You can do: `grep -iq -e "SUCCESS" -e "Leaving" "compile.log"` for that case.

Comment: -e for the patern and -i to ignore the case. Thanks anubhava.

Answer (score 18):

`[[` triggers the test command. Test doesn't support testing the exit status of a command just by typing the command

Comment: How would you fix it?

Comment: I came here to look for; briefly what brackets mean. Thanks.